# Add 7 days to values in Access date column

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a date of journey column in Access with DateTime data type. 
I want to update it to [date of journey] + 7 using VB.Net, but it shows the error:

> Data type criteria mismatch

What should i do?
Here is the query I'm using.

```
Dim update as String = "update [Bus Schedule] set [Date of journey] = [Date of journey] + 7"
```

Comment: Not able to test, your should try with _set [Date of journey] = DateAdd('d', 7, [Date of journey])_

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working properly @Steve

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply use the + operator to add an undefined amount to a Date column.
Instead you need to use the DateAdd specifying what the amount represent ('d' for days), the amount to increment (or decrement) and finally the field where the operation will be applied

```
Dim update as String = "UPDATE [Bus Schedule] 
                        SET [Date of journey] = DateAdd('d', 7, [Date of journey])"
```

For other options see
[DateAdd Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63BEFDF6-1FFA-4357-9424-61E8C57AFC19)

Comment: Actually in Access you can do `UPDATE MyTable SET DateColumn = [DateColumn]+7;` just fine - Access uses the Double number that date/time values are stored as.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's working properly @Steve